# Equation Similar to Lamé Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

I have an equation similar to the Lamé differential equation in the Jacobi form, defined as

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + (a\,\mathrm{sn}(x)^2+b)y(x)=0$$

where the function $\mathrm{sn}(x)$ is one of the Jacobi elliptic functions.  My equation takes the form

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \left[k^2-\alpha_1\left(\frac{1-\gamma_1\mathrm{sn}^2(\gamma_2 x,\beta)}{r-\gamma_1\mathrm{sn}^2(\gamma_2 x,\beta)}\right)-\alpha_2\left(\frac{r-\gamma_1\mathrm{sn}^2(\gamma_2 x,\beta)}{1-\gamma_1\mathrm{sn}^2(\gamma_2 x,\beta)}\right)^2\right]y(x)$$

where $k,r,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta,\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are all real constants. I recognize this could also be viewed as Schrodinger's equation in one dimension with a tricky non-periodic potential, so I've looked at methods to solve that too.

For background on the Lamé differential equation, check Chapter XV of **Higher Transcendental Functions** (http://apps.nrbook.com/bateman/Vol3.pdf) and the last chapter in **A Course of Modern Analysis** (https://archive.org/details/courseofmodernan00whit).

The goal is to find an exact closed-form solution if possible.  I believe there is some transformation I might be able to use to put the equation in a nicer form, but I can't quite find it.

**EDIT**: When I use the transformation $z=1-\gamma_1\mathrm{sn}^2(x)$ I get something that looks like Heun's differential equation, but with *slightly* different forms for the polynomials. Are there any known generalizations?

Comment: for what stands $sn$?

Comment: It is one of the Jacobi elliptic functions, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html

Comment: the usual transformation for the lame equation is $z=am(x)$, where $am(x)$ is the Jacobi amplitude

Comment: When I use that transformation I get a differential equation for $y(z)$ with a $dy/dz$ term, and it doesn't seem easier to solve.

Comment: But it becomes algebraic, then you can work with usual methods.

Comment: Quick question - the elliptic form of the differential equation has only regular singularities, but when I make the transformation $z=sn^2(x)$ (or anything similar), I end up with irregular singularities.  Can I take a power series solution without worrying about these new singularities?  What is the general rule for singularities introduced by a change of variable?